# Cant read file when passing directory full path as defined const in Php

Tags: php

I have an upload php file and the form post action file.
Everything goes well but only one issue I wish to resolve:
When my form post action file has the directory defined as a literal string:

```
$uploaddir = "uploadpics/temps/";
```

pictures can be read by the calling php file although the files themselves are uploaded as **www-data** user.

if I change:

```
$uploaddir = DIR_TEMPS;
```

Where **DIR_TEMPS** defined in a php config file:

```
define('DIR_TEMPS',    DIR_EXH . 'temps/'); // full path concatenated $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

pictures can **NOT** be read by the calling php file although the files themselves are **still** uploaded as **www-data** user.
Can anyone tell me why?? how can I make this work/ fix it???
Or what am I doing wrong??

Note: just checked again and tried:

```
$uploaddir = "" . DIR_TEMPS;
```

Still cant read the file.
BUT, when I define:

```
define('DIR_TEMPS1',    'uploadpics/temps/');
$uploaddir = DIR_TEMPS1;
```

All works well.

What is the difference then??

Comment: `echo DIR_TEMPS` - what does that give you?

Comment: /var/www/website/public_html/uploadpics/temps/. I know the issue is with FULL PATH vs local (sort of speak) PATH

Comment: Well, is `/var/www/website/public_html/uploadpics/temps/` the same as `uploadpics/temps/` relative to your current directory...?

Comment: yes it is. I know this is quite odd...